# Configuring JSF/ICEFaces InputFile programmatically

Tags: java, jsf, file-upload, icefaces

I have an InputFile isntance put on my form from Java code like this:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

MethodExpressionActionListener meal = new MethodExpressionActionListener(context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createMethodExpression(context.getELContext(), "#{mybackingbean.fileUploadEvent}", null,
        new Class[] { ActionEvent.class }));

InputFile inputFile = new InputFile();
inputFile.setAutoUpload(false);
inputFile.addActionListener(meal);
//inputFile.setActionExpression(...) - did not work
//inputFile.setAction(..) - did not work

parent.getChildren().add(inputFile);
```

The component renders correctly, after clicking the upload button the browser sends the POST request but my backing bean is never notified. I tried the similar-looking `setActionExpression` and `setAction` methods as well to bind the component to my bean but nothing happens.

Do you have any ideas how to make my backing bean aware of the file upload outcome..?

**Updated**

Switching on more logging I can see that the file is uploaded and this is logged:

```
2011-12-07 22:12:54,097 UploadServer DEBUG - UploadServer  doLifecycle :: Window00303:j_id117 in form 'Window00303' -> FileInfo: {
  percent=100,
  preUpload=false,
  postUpload=false,
  exception=null,
  fileName=abcchmvw.INI,
  file=[...],
  physicalPath=[...],
  contentType=application/octet-stream,
  size=437,
  status=2
}
```

I decompiled the `UploadServer` but can't see the reason why my actionListener should be called.

Comment: Double checked that the FileUploadServlet is alive and listening

Comment: BalusC, any ideas..? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is `addActionListener` but the important thing that failed all was not setting an id for the component via calling `setId()`